# Post request with multiples buttons to different functions in the same controller

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a blade view. When the user select an item a modal view appears in the same HTML.

My modal have 3 buttons. Each button have to redirect by **post** request to specific functions in my controller.

**CarsController**

```
class CarsControllerextends Controller
{
    index(){
        ...
        return view('cars')->with(['car'=>$response]);
    }

    // execute when the user click on save button
    save(Request $request){
         ...
    }
    // execute when the user click on delete button
    delete(Request $request){
         ...
    }
    // execute when the user click on remove button
    remove(Request $request){
         ...
    }

}
```

**Modal**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/guardarTurno') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
<!-- 3 hidden inputs to save the id of the item that the user selected ... is the best way?--> 

    <input type="hidden" id="cancha" name="cancha" value=""  class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" id="fecha" name="fecha" value="{{$agenda['fechaElegida']}}"  class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" id="hora" name="hora" value=""  class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success button-infousuario">
        <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></span>
        Save
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-warning button-infousuario">
    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-fw"></i></span>
        Delete
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger button-infousuario">
        <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></span>
        Remove
    </button>
</form>
```

What I want is:

> Save button make a post request to save() method
>
> Remove button make a post request to remove() method
>
> Delete button make a post request to delete() method

Each of three button need the same ids

Thanks!

Comment: Did you notice http method such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE ?

Comment: If I was you, I'll try different routes to target controller with different function. And, using like `<a href="YourRoute">Delete</a>`

Comment: I can't. Is a custom class and a custom logic to make for each button

Comment: i think I can't make a post request by href

Comment: Off course, what I meant is post request is only for create new cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make 3 different forms to send to 3 different functions.

After your `Save` button, close the first `</form>`.

Then start a new form for each of the remaining buttons (Delete & Remove). Each form  will have a different action

```
<form action="/remove" method="post"> 
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1' />
    <button type='submit'>Remove</button>
</form>
```

Then the same for `Delete`

Don't forget to define routes for each of the `action=''`

Comment: But for ech button I have to replicate the 3 hidden input with 3 different name?

Comment: you can keep the same name. just the route has to be different. This is because you want to post. WOuld be easier with GET. Since you want to post, replicate the hidden input. with the same name. It doesnt matter. They are all different forms

Comment: also I see some of your hidden inputs have empty values. Moreover, remove `class` from hidden inputs. They don't need styling because they are invisible.

Comment: Shall I need a post request for remove? Shall I make a change in my structure? I want best practices

Comment: The inout fill with jquery when the user click in the item

Comment: Best practices would want you to use `DELETE` instead of `POST` for deleting. However, it's also ok with POST. Using GET might actually expose your URL. You don't want that. Users could play with the url and enter random values.

Comment: Also they can do it with the inputs hidden value. A little more complicated but if he know how to change the value in the url also he know for sure how to modify the input value haha. Of course in server site I have to make the validations